# Pandas: date_range error

Tags: python, date, pandas

I'm getting an error using pandas `date_range` function. I've given the trace below, and can provide more context, but it seems like something I'm really going to have to dig into myself to solve.

So what I'd like to know is if there's a way to get at the source for the files mentioned in the trace, specifically `datetime.pyx`, or wherever the Timestamp class is defined - I can't seem to find it. I'm pretty green with Python and don't know my way around packages and sources very well, but I'm hoping that if I can dig a little deeper I'll be able to shed some light on this.

```
>>> d=process_files(args, options, False)
Processing file K2.csv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/py7041Jtp.py", line 158, in process_files
  File "/tmp/py7041Jtp.py", line 81, in process_csv
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.8.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/tseries/index.py", line 1317, in date_range
    freq=freq, tz=tz, normalize=normalize, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.8.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/tseries/index.py", line 176, in __new__
    tz=tz, normalize=normalize)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.8.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/tseries/index.py", line 254, in _generate
    start = Timestamp(start)
  File "datetime.pyx", line 87, in pandas.lib.Timestamp.__new__ (pandas/src/tseries.c:26892)
  File "datetime.pyx", line 511, in pandas.lib.convert_to_tsobject (pandas/src/tseries.c:32019)
  File "datetime.pyx", line 640, in pandas.lib._string_to_dts (pandas/src/tseries.c:33452)
```

Comment: It parses a bunch of csv files into dataframes. Not really important though - the error always originates in the pandas sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was just parsing the wrong field, based on a command switch that defaulted to `None`. Not thinking clearly :/

Answer (score 1):

To find datetime.pyx, I'd suggest starting with:

```
find /usr/local/lib/python2.7 -name 'datetime.pyx'
```

To find the definition of the Timestamp class, I'd start with:

```
grep -r 'class Timestamp' /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0<tab>
```

Comment: Yup tried those, but no luck - probably going to grab the source

Comment: @roysc: [Sounds good](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/learn-to-read-the-source-luke.html). Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

The `.pyx` files are Cython files.  You might find them installed, but they might not be if you didn't build the library from source.  However, all the pandas source is available on github.  The source for `datetime.pyx` is [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/src/datetime.pyx).

Cython looks similar to Python, so if you're just trying to browse the source to figure out what's causing the error, you might find it useful to see the Cython source.  But you won't be able to debug it like regular Python, because it's not.

Comment: Excellent point...I can never remember which files Cython actually installs.

Answer (score 1):

For you convenience i copied `pandas.lib._string_to_dts` function code below.
Based on your traceback, this is the one throwing the exception.

```
cdef inline _string_to_dts(object val, pandas_datetimestruct* dts):
  cdef:
      npy_bool islocal, special
      PANDAS_DATETIMEUNIT out_bestunit
      int result

  if PyUnicode_Check(val):
      val = PyUnicode_AsASCIIString(val);

  result = parse_iso_8601_datetime(val, len(val), PANDAS_FR_ns,
                                   NPY_UNSAFE_CASTING,
                                   dts, &islocal, &out_bestunit, &special)
  if result == -1:
      raise ValueError('Unable to parse %s' % str(val))
```

To me it looks like you provide input to `pandas.date_range` which can not be parsed to a date and your code in `process_csv` throws a `ValueError` exception like in the example below.

```
>>> import pandas
>>> pandas.date_range('hello')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.8.2.dev_90842ba-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/tseries/index.py", line 1317, in date_range
    freq=freq, tz=tz, normalize=normalize, name=name)
  File "../lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.8.2.dev_90842ba-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/tseries/index.py", line 176, in __new__
    tz=tz, normalize=normalize)
  File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.8.2.dev_90842ba-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/tseries/index.py", line 254, in _generate
    start = Timestamp(start)
  File "datetime.pyx", line 87, in pandas.lib.Timestamp.__new__ (pandas/src/tseries.c:26892)
  File "datetime.pyx", line 511, in pandas.lib.convert_to_tsobject (pandas/src/tseries.c:32019)
  File "datetime.pyx", line 640, in pandas.lib._string_to_dts (pandas/src/tseries.c:33452)
ValueError: Unable to parse hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Please post potential bug reports on GitHub (or the mailing list). Thanks-- although this did get more answers than GitHub would have.